# Does Bash support a way of "triggering" an event?

Tags: bash, triggers

I have a couple of bahs scripts running at the same time, and they communicate with each other by saving trigger variables in a folder. So one script will do something, and when its done it will echo "done" > variablefolder. The second script has a loop, checking every now and then if there is a "done" in the variable folder. If it is, the script executes something.

Does Bash support any better way of doing this? I know about *export name=value*, but that in practice does pretty much the same as what I'm doing now. I'm thinking, is there any way of pushing information to a Bash script that reacts on it? So when something is pushed to it, the Bash script will run a function, or something?

Comment: @JohnC Thank you. I've now googles signals in Bash, and it might be what I'm looking for. I guess I should use SIGINT for the listening script, but how do I send a signal from another script for the listening one to catch?

Comment: just use the kill command!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to handle inter-process communications is to use signals...

To send a signal to another process you can use the kill command.
The kill command uses the process id to identify the process.
You can save the process id to a file after the script starts using the `$$` variable

Here is an example of a script that will catch a signal:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $$ > /tmp/pid  # Save the pid

function do_stuff {
   echo "I am doing stuff"
   exit
}

trap do_stuff SIGINT

while `true`
do
   echo "Waiting for a signal"
   sleep 1
done
```

So to send it a signal you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
pid=`cat /tmp/pid`  # Read the pid
kill -s INT $pid
```

Comment: Thank you very much. So kill isn't actually only used to kill (i.e terminate) programs? I did a short googling on kill -s, and that sends a signal without it being a "terminate" signal, right?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  The idea is that if your program is well behaved it will catch the signal and shutdown cleanly.  If that fails you can send the `-9` signal which can't be caught by the program and it gets killed by the operating system.  Lots of programs use signals to reload their config file also.

Comment: I'be been playing around with sigint and trap, but no matter what, it does terminate the script once it has run the function "do_stuff". Is there any way to make it keep going after having run the function? So never actually being terminated?

Comment: Sure, just remove the line that says `exit`

Comment: That I've already done, but it seems to get stuck when it's done with the function. I have a loop that starts with "do while :", that I want to be infinite. Inside it is a paus, that starts with "while `true`". Every time the "paus loop" traps a signal, I want it to run the function. And then return to the infinite loop. But it seems to break the infinite loop too. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code.  I suggest opening another question.  Include your code and layout the problem you are having.